# how can i put (keras/apply_affine_transform) to work ? (theta)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, affinetransform

**I'm trying to rotate an image with keras affine tranformation (theta).

the output i'm reveiving is:**

[output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6g1T.png)

```
import skimage.io as io  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np

image = io.imread("dog.jpg")  
plt.imshow(image)  
plt.show()

import tensorflow as tf  
transformed=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform(image, theta=45) 
plt.imshow(transformed)  
plt.show()
```

**What can i do to rotate the image with affine transformation ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `row_axis=0`, `col_axis=1`, `channel_axis=2` to `apply_affine_transform()`'s arguments.

Your image's memory layout is "channels-last", but the function thinks it is "channels-first". It (incorrectly) thinks the image laid out as `[C,H,W]`, rather than `[H,W,C]`.